# Failed Login User - Send automatic Email Notification

Tags: password, users, email

please assist - I want to write a script in Ubuntu/Linux which can send an automatic email notification to admin if any user failed to login three times by providing an incorrect password.

**Note:** I have set up the email notification but just want to know how can I get the User Identification / IP address/location and incorporate them in the email if the user doesn't have the authenticity to access.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, how the user can access your computer anyway. They need to come and plug into your computer or use `ssh` beforehand, in my thoughts.

Comment: Yes User will use my computer but if User use 'ssh' what will be the script though? Btw, I am not expert in Ubuntu env and I am in a learning stage so suggest me the best practice to keep the system secure and safe.

Comment: I have managed to configure the automatic email notification. Thanks.